# WSO2 ESB: Display dataService response

Tags: sequence, wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

How do you display the response returned by calling a webservice endpoint on a sequence?

Below is the sequence that I use. I would like to display the return value from the dataservice called "CDServiceEndpoint" on the wso2carbon.log. Is that possible? If not, how can I get the data displayed.

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="ConcurGetADPExtractFlow" onError="GeneralErrorHandler">
   <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xmlns:ns3="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="current-context-details" expression="concat(get-property('current-context-details'), ', ConcurGetADPExtractFlow')" />
   <property name="scenario" value="ConcurGetADPExtractFlow" />
   <log level="custom">
      <property name="DEBUGGING" value="ConcurGetADPExtractFlow" />
      <property name="start-date" value="2015-02-23" />
      <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xmlns:ns3="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="End Date" expression="get-property('current-date')" />
   </log>
   <xslt key="Concur_Get_ADP_Extract_Transformation">
      <property name="start-date" value="2015-03-02" />
      <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xmlns:ns3="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="end-date" expression="get-property('current-date')" />
   </xslt>
   <property name="post-data-service-sequence" value="ConcurTransformADPExtractFlow" />
   <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="false" />
   <send receive="DataServiceInvocationErrorFlow">
      <endpoint key="ConcurDataServiceEndpoint" />
   </send>
   <description>Sends a request to the data service for the ADP extract data.</description>
</sequence>
```

Below is how my DataServiceInvocationErrorFlow looks like.

```
 <sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="DataServiceInvocationErrorFlow">
   <filter xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xmlns:m="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice" xmlns:ns3="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xpath="//m:DataServiceFault">
      <then>
         <log level="custom">
            <property name="status" value="data-service-fault" />
         </log>
         <property name="error_message" expression="//m:DataServiceFault" />
         <sequence key="GeneralErrorHandler" />
         <drop />
      </then>
      <else>
         <filter source="string-length(get-property('ERROR_MESSAGE'))" regex="0.0">
            <then>
               <filter xpath="//soapenv:Fault">
                  <then>
                     <log level="custom">
                        <property name="status" value="ERROR" />
                     </log>
                     <property name="error_message" expression="//soapenv:Fault" />
                     <sequence key="GeneralErrorHandler" />
                     <drop />
                  </then>
                  <else>
                     <log level="custom">
                        <property name="status" value="success response from DSS" />
                     </log>
                     <filter source="string-length(normalize-space(get-property('post-data-service-sequence')))" regex="0.0">
                        <then />
                        <else>
                           <property name="temp-post-data-service-sequence" expression="get-property('post-data-service-sequence')" />
                           <property name="post-data-service-sequence" value="" />
                           <sequence key="{get-property('temp-post-data-service-sequence')}" />
                        </else>
                     </filter>
                  </else>
               </filter>
            </then>
            <else>
               <property name="error_message" expression="get-property('ERROR_MESSAGE')" />
               <sequence key="GeneralErrorHandler" />
               <drop />
            </else>
         </filter>
      </else>
   </filter>
</sequence>
```

Answer (score 0):

If by `CDServiceEndpoint` you meant `ConcurDataServiceEndpoint`, then you are already handling the response from that endpoint in your `DataServiceInvocationErrorFlow` sequence that you defined on the `Send` mediator, which by the way is confusingly named, since your `receive` sequence will run no matter if you get an error response or a good one. All you need to do is log it inside `DataServiceInvocationErrorFlow` using Log mediator.

Had you not defined a `receive` sequence on your `Send` mediator, the response would have gotten to your `outSequence`, where you can log it with Log mediator too.

Comment: Thanks Voicu, I have added my answer as another another on this thread. And yes, by CDServiceEndpoint I mean ConcurDataServiceEndPoint.

Comment: @Gopi: So handle your successful responses in the `DataServiceInvocationErrorFlow` too and maybe change its name so it does not reflect an error flow only. Please note that you are currently filtering out any non-error message in there.